# Instant close DrawerLayout

Tags: android

I am having trouble finding out how to instantly close the menu in the DrawerLayout, without any animations.

What I want to achive is to have the menu automatically closed every time a user comes back to the activity.
Maybe there is a better way, other than closing the drawers in onStop() or onResume()?

Thanks in advance,
Ivan